# Any invertible linear map $L$ can be written as $AB$ with $A$ unitary and $B$ psd: a rigorous argument?

Tags: linear-algebra

Please teach me how to argue for this rigorously:
The question:

> $L$ is an invertible linear map with $L\in (V,V)$. Prove that $L$ can be written as $AB$ where $A^\dagger A=I=AA^\dagger$ and $B$ is positive-definite.

*What I think:*

This is intuitively true because $L^\dagger L$ is positive-definite. So $L^\dagger L=B^\dagger B$ for some positive definite $B$ which does not necessarily equal $L$. To correct for that, we throw in $A$ which cancels.

I don't know how to present this rigorously though. Thanks in advance.

*Added:* Curious, what can I say about a general $L\in (V,V)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) if you are working with finite dimensional real or complex vector spaces.

Comment: The same method answers the "Added" question, showing that for singular matrices you just replace "positive definite" with "positive semidefinite".